# Non-inferiority testing for a $2 \times 2$ design when assay sensitivity is not achieved

Tags: non-inferiority

Suppose we are testing the hypothesis:

$$\mathcal{H}_0 : \pi_1 < \pi_0 + \delta$$ versus $$\mathcal{H}_0 : \pi_1 > \pi_0 + \delta$$
where $\delta$ is the non-inferiority margin. $\pi_1$ and $\pi_0$ is the probability of success for a certain outcome in groups 1 (investigational treatment) and 0 (control) respectively.

The experimental results are given by the $2 \times 2$ summary table:

$$ \begin{array}[c|cc] 
& & \text{Non-event} & \text{Event} \\ \hline
\text{Control} & y_{00} & y_{10} \\ 
\text{Active} & y_{01} & y_{11} \end{array}$$

and the test statistic for significance in a superiority hypothesis is given by:

$$T = \frac{\log(y_{00}) + \log(y_{11}) - \log(y_{10}) - \log(y_{01})}{\sqrt{1/y_{11} + 1/y_{00} + 1/y_{01} + 1/y_{10}}}$$

If we were testing for a mean difference in a T-test we would simply "offset" the observed mean in the control group by $\delta$. However, to test for a difference in proportions, do we replace ALL $y_{00}$ and $y_{01}$ with an equivalent $y_{00} + \delta n_0$ and $y_{01} - \delta n_0$ respectively? Or is that substitution made in *both the numerator and the denominator*?

Equivalently, would the same hold if we considered the Wald test statistic

$$ T = \frac{y_{11}/n_0 - y_{10}/n_1 - \delta}{\sqrt{p^{*}(1-p^{*})(1/n_0 + 1/n_1)}}$$

i.e. is the pooled variance using the "control" calculated using the observed variance in the control, or a predicted variance based on what the control would be if it were on the boundary of inferiority?